# JSON, Swiper JS: Can't create carousel of images from Array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, fetch

I have a [JSON](https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/dragons/5e9d058759b1ff74a7ad5f8f), which contains array of images (.flickr_images).

I have to create a carousel of images. In codepen all images works fine, but in VSCode I have an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1gPD.png).

Tried this method

```
<div class="swiper">
   <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="" alt="Dragon" class="image_dragon">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="" alt="Dragon" class="image_dragon">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="" alt="Dragon" class="image_dragon">
      </div>
      <div class="swiper-slide">
          <img src="" alt="Dragon" class="image_dragon">
      </div>
                        
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    </div>
```

```
fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/dragons/5e9d058759b1ff74a7ad5f8f')
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then((d) => {
        document.querySelectorAll('.image_dragon').forEach((el, i) => (el.src = d.flickr_images[i]));
    });
```

**Working Snippet:**

```js
fetch('https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/dragons/5e9d058759b1ff74a7ad5f8f')
  .then((r) => r.json())
  .then((d) => {
    document.querySelectorAll('.image_dragon').forEach((el, i) => (el.src = d.flickr_images[i]));
    initCarousel();
  });


function initCarousel() {

  const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
        cssMode: true,
        navigation: {
          nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
          prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
        },
        pagination: {
          el: ".swiper-pagination",
        },
        mousewheel: true,
        keyboard: true,
        loop: true
      });

}
```

```css
html,
      body {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
      }

      body {
        background: #eee;
        font-family: Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .swiper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
      }

      .swiper-slide {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 18px;
        background: #fff;

        /* Center slide text vertically */
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
        -webkit-justify-content: center;
        justify-content: center;
        -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
        -webkit-align-items: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .swiper-slide img {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
      
      .swiper-button-prev,
      .swiper-button-next,
      .swiper-pagination {
         background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
         border-radius: 5px;
         padding: 10px;
      }
      
      .swiper-button-prev:hover,
      .swiper-button-next:hover,
      .swiper-pagination:hover {
          background-color: white;
       }
```

```html
<div class="swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="" alt="Dragon" class="image_dragon">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="" alt="Dragon" class="image_dragon">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="" alt="Dragon" class="image_dragon">
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-slide">
      <img src="" alt="Dragon" class="image_dragon">
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.css" />

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@8/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Any why do you think you get 403 forbidden error on one the images?

Comment: @KonradLinkowski I understand the error code, but I don't understand how to solve it

Comment: @Yogi Same problem, in any website this works great!!! But not in VSCode => live.server.

Comment: Please see updated solution.

Comment: Yes! It finally works! Thanks a lot @Yogi!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Referrer Policy**

The solution to the problem is simple, yet interesting and good to know. The fix is to add the following attribute to each image element:

```
referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
```

And you can test the fix by pasting the following html into a page and then opening it with VSCode Live Server. With the attribute set it displays normally, but with it removed it is blocked (403). And make sure to disable browser caching for this test to work correctly.

```
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/9fWdwNv.jpg" referrerpolicy="no-referrer">
```

And yet if we post the same html into [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7vwcb39j/) it works both with and without the attribute.

**So what is going on here?**

Servers may restrict access to resources, like images, based on some configuration. They might require the user to be authenticated or to make the request from a certain domain.  In this case, Flickr is blocking one of the images. It's most likely only blocking the request from VSCode Live Server because it is using http localhost. Yet, we can get around that by setting the referrer policy.

Special Case: The results can be unpredictable when you have multiple images with the same src but mixed referrer policy attributes. So it's probably better to set them all the same.

*This solution can work with other sites besides just Flickr, which is why it's a good trick to know.*

**Further reading**

The attribute and associated header have a number of possible values and you can read more about them at MDN [Referrer-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy) and [HTMLImageElement.referrerPolicy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/referrerPolicy)

```
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Referrer-Policy: origin
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin
Referrer-Policy: same-origin
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Referrer-Policy: unsafe-url
```